# Using variables across django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, backend, django-urls

I have a link in a layout template that another template extends. i want the link to pass in a variable thats in the template that extends the other. I want to pass the name variable in the documentPage template through the editDoc link in the layout template. can anyone think of a way to do this? thanks
[image: template with the variable]
[image: template with the link]

Comment: Please don't provide code as screen shots.  Instead, copy/paste the text itself into your question.  You're more likely to get a good answer if you follow the rules and do this.  Many readers, me included, will not bother to read your question tif it is not formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

In views.py file, you can pass the link as a context dictionary to template:

```
def function_name(request):
    generated_link = 'generated_link'
    context = {
       'link': generated_link 
    }
    return render(request,"documentPage.html",context=context)
```

You can extends template as :

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block body %}

 # Write body here
 <a href="{{link}}">Click Me</a>

{% endblock %}
```